# Looping over json results

Tags: jquery, json, loops

I have the following json results being returned to me and I can't work out how to loop over the success results. Here is an example of what is being returned

```
{"ERRORS":[],"SUCCESS":["7336","7337","7356"]}
```

This is where I have got to so far but it's not working

```
jQuery.each( data.success, function( i, val ) {
   console.log(val);
});
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: data.SUCCESS instead of data.success

Comment: javacsript is case sensitive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make success same case.

```
jQuery.each( data.SUCCESS, function( i, val ) {
   console.log(val);
});
```

JavaScript is case sensitive. I would recommend using lower case letters (camelCase) when working with json - but it's a matter of preference of course.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need the parameter passing when using jQuery.each.

Try this:

```
jQuery.each(data.SUCCESS, function() {
   console.log(this);
});
```

Comment: Well, it's still represents the same value.

Comment: Yes, as Johan said, it makes no difference. The correct part of your answer is the `data.SUCCESS` part.